# convert curl php rest api calls to c# code

Tags: c#, api, rest, curl

I've been trying to convert php code that accesses a json rest api into c# but cannot get this to work...

I cannot get a valid response back..  (400 Bad request)

Here is the curl im trying to convert:

```
curl --user bob@gmail.com:387653t253431a1b1d6687pl9836th5s \
--form url=http://bbc.com --form x-metrix-adblock=0 \
https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test
```

Here is the code I've tried without success:

```
content = "http://bbc.com";
string result;
var req = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test");
req.Method = "POST";
var cc = new CredentialCache();

req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, passkey);
req.ContentType = "application/json";
byte[] bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (var stream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
{
    var results = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    result = JObject.Parse(results).ToString();
}
```

any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I wanted to let you know that I’ve released an open source .Net client library which simplifies consuming the GTMetrix.net API. Submitting a test and retrieving the results is simple;

```
var client = Client(connection);   

var request = new TestRequest(
    new Uri("http://website.net"),
    Locations.London,
    Browsers.Chrome);                          

var response = client.SubmitTestAsync(request);

if (response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && 
    response.Result.Body.State == ResultStates.Completed)
{
    var pageLoadTime = response.Result.Body.Results.PageLoadTime;
    ...
}
```

The project (docs and code) can be found here [GTmetrix-net on GitHub](https://github.com/Kevin-Bronsdijk/gtmetrix-net)